# PackageManager in Android giving duplicates

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I might be a novice programmer but PackageManager is complicated !
What I am going to show you makes no sense:

I am able to pull out the names of applications on the device however if I try to save to array then I can only save half of them.

```
        PackageManager packageManager = null;
    List<ApplicationInfo> appsListTest = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
    packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    appsListTest = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(0);
    Log.d("LOG", " New PM : " + appsListTest.size());

    Iterator<ApplicationInfo> iterator = appsListTest.iterator();
    int counter = 0;
    String[] appName = new String[appsListTest.size()];
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {

        Log.d("LOG", String.valueOf(counter));
    //  When I print out by itself I see 64 apps. Great
        Log.d("LOG", (String) iterator.next().loadLabel(packageManager));
    //  Now when I try to save to array I only get 30
                    appName[counter] = (String) iterator.next().loadLabel(packageManager);
        counter++;


    }
```

It makes no sense !!!

So if I comment out the appName array I will print Log.d out 61 times.
But when I include that array then I will only log out 31 times.

And the value i initialise appName to is 64:

```
Log.d("LOG", " New PM : " + appsListTest.size());
```

Application does not crash or anything.

Can anyone show me some code on how to get app name, uid and icon ?

Answer (score 0):

`iterator.next()` advances the list - you are advancing it twice per loop. Instead, you should save the result from `iterator.next()` as a variable and then use that within the loop:

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Log.d("LOG", String.valueOf(counter));
    // Only call iterator.next() once per loop
    ApplicationInfo info = iterator.next();
    String label = (String) info.loadLabel(packageManager);
    Log.d("LOG", label);
    appName[counter] = label;
    counter++;
}
```